# Delimiters between possibly hidden spans

Tags: css, html

I have a number of spans, forming an enumeration:

```
<span class="item">Value 1</span><span class="delim">, </span>
<span class="item">Value 2</span><span class="delim">, </span>
<span class="item">Value 3</span>
```

It's OK when all of `item` has `display:inline`, but when I add a class with `display:none` to the second `item` span, the result looks like the following:

> Value 1, , Value 2

I couldn't find a solution to this problem within CSS, and using JS is undesirable (the code which toggles visibility is already very complicated).

Any ideas?

**UPDATE.** As of the current moment, all of proposed solutions miss the fact that ANY of `item` spans can be hidden or visible, not only the second one. The problem is not only the double comma in the middle, but also an extra comma in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use so called [general sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector):

```
.item.active ~ .item.active:before {
    content: ', ';
}
```

Commas are only inserted before those visible items, whose parent has another visible item as a child, and that child precedes our in the document.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution with just CSS:

```
.item:before{
    content: ", ";
}
.item:first-child:before{
    content: "";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8aEhz/

Comment: It doesn't fit if the first item is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the span with the value isn't the parent of the delimited span. In order to hide the delimiter when hiding the value span, you'll have to contain them inside the value span, like so:

```
<span class="item">Value 1<span class="delim">, </span></span>
<span class="item">Value 2<span class="delim">, </span></span>
<span class="item">Value 3</span>
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem in question, with extra comma?

Comment: Nah, the `delim` spans are **inside** the `item` spans in my code (they are separate in his). This means that when he hides the `item`, the child `delim` is also hidden :)

Comment: If the first and the second `item` spans are visible and the third one is hidden, there will be a comma in the end — that's not what I wanted.

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky Ah are we allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: The problem can be solved easily with JS, but I'm interested in pure HTML/CSS solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/whQxW/

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.hidden + .delim {
    display: none;
}
```

it gives

> Value 1, Value 3

This looks like a good introduction to sibling selectors: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/. You should probably get to know them - they're quite powerful.

Comment: This will hide ALL of the `.delim` elements that follow a `.hidden` element: http://jsfiddle.net/whQxW/1/ The selector should be `.hidden + .delim`; http://jsfiddle.net/whQxW/3/

Comment: No problem. Here is another excellent link about selectors that I think you might like - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: Of course, I've already tried sibling selectors, but that's not a proper solution: try a case when only the first item is not hidden — it will have a comma after it.